# Need help developing sub-range

Tags: python, random, probability

Write a program that reads a positive integer N and outputs a random sequence of N
integers in the range [1;100] such that each integer x in the sequence is generated according
to the following probability distribution. First, a sub-range is chosen for x, with sub-range
[1;25] chosen with probability 1/8, the sub-range [26;50] with probability y 1/2, the sub-range [51;75] with probability 1/4, and the sub-range [76;100] with probability 1/8.Once
a sub-range for x has been chosen (e.g., [1;25]) then a value for x is picked uniformly at random from that sub-range.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help needed for homework without attempting _anything at all_.

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should be answerable. This question is likely to require an extended discussion on the design and implementation of the program.

Comment: @user2357112 ...which is _too broad_ for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it short. Your range has probability ratio of 1:4:2:1. So...

```
H = range(1,26)+range(26,51)*4+range(51,76)*2+range(76,101)
```

Then use `random.randrange` function.

```
from random import randrange
a  = H[randrange(len(H))]
```